# "Hatte geschlafen gehabt" als Plusquamperfekt?

Tags: tense, regional, perfect-tense, past-participle, pluperfect

In diesem Ausschnitt aus *Neue Vahr Süd*, von Sven Regener, verwendet der Erzähler das Plusquamperfekt, um zu erzählen, was der Hauptfigur früher am Tag passiert war:

> ... er hatte sich morgens um fünf aus dem Haus geschlichen, da hatte
> sie noch geschlafen, er dagegen **hatte noch überhaupt nicht geschlafen
> gehabt** und war auch, nachdem er sie verlassen hatte, noch wach
> geblieben und ein bisschen durch die Gegend gelaufen...

Das "gehabt" kommt mir ganz überflüssig vor, vielleicht kann mir jemand dessen Zweck erklären. Geht es um Stil? Wird es regional so gesprochen (die Hauptfigur stammt aus Bremen)?

Comment: Du möchtest möglicherweise diesen Artikel lesen, dein Beispiel wäre damit "Ultra-Plusquamperfekt": https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-das-ultra-perfekt-a-295317.html
Alternativ auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppeltes_Perfekt

Im Übrigen ist das kein spezifisch deutsches Phänomen, sondern kommt in vielen europäischen Sprachen vor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfekthilfsverben lassen sich iterieren; dann entstehen Doppelformen (die Belege kommen aus der "Systematischen Grammatik" des IDS, [Formenbestand des deutschen Tempussystems](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/232)):

> Die Kleine hat den Nerz in einer Pelzhandlung gestohlen gehabt.
> (Abendpost 11.11.1965, o.S.)
>
> Nach seiner Rückkehr ließ Zeffirelli den Burgtheaterdirektor wissen, er habe seinen Agenten lediglich beauftragt gehabt, Bedenken wegen des Zeitpunktes anzumelden (...).
> (Welt, 21.10.1966, 9)
>
> Der Landesvorsitzende der SPD (...) bedauerte, daß das Gespräch mit der katholischen Kirche erst in Gang gekommen sei, nachdem sich die Fraktionen festgelegt gehabt hätten. (Nachrichten aus Rheinland-Pfalz und Baden-Württemberg 6.3.1967, ARD, Hörzitat)
>
> Buster hatte einmal schon die Flugkarten nach Nizza bestellt gehabt, aber dann war ihm etwas dazwischengekommen.
> (Kuby, Das Mädchen Rosemarie, 87)

Das *hatte noch überhaupt nicht geschlafen gehabt* aus dem in der Frage zitierten Text hat  klar die Funktion der Vor-Vorzeitigkeit: das Nichtschlafen geht dem Aus-dem-Haus-Schleichen voran bzw. war schon abgeschlossen, als letzteres stattfand. Wenn das Doppelperfekt<sup>*</sup> eine Funktion hat und im literarischen Kontext verwendet wird, ist es nicht regional gebunden und auch nicht überflüssig; es ist eine echte (aber völlig optionale und daher nicht unbedingt häufig auftretende) Erweiterung des Tempussystems.

<sup>* Zur Terminologie: Wenn man an der fürs Lateinische gedachten Opposition *Perfekt* und *Plusquamperfekt* festhält, müßte man hier von *Doppelplusquamperfekt* sprechen. In einer am IDS angelehnten Terminologie kann man dagegen einfach vom *(Indikativ) Präteritum Doppelperfekt* sprechen.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Der ganze Abschnitt ist im Plusquamperfekt um ihn voran des jetzt-Zeitpunkts in der Geschichte zu positionieren. Wäre der Roman im Präsens geschrieben, würde man dafür einfach das Perfekt/Präteritum benutzen, und dann würde ein normales Plusquamperfekt ausreichen um noch weiter davor liegenden (nicht-) Schlaf zu beschreiben:

> ... er hat sich morgens um fünf aus dem Haus geschlichen, da schlief sie noch, er dagegen **hatte noch überhaupt nicht geschlafen** und ist auch, nachdem er sie verlassen hatte, noch wach geblieben und ein bisschen durch die Gegend gelaufen...

Nun hat aber der ganze Roman schon das Präteritum als die Jetzt-Form, sodass also dieser Perfekt-Abschnitt ins Plusquamperfekt fällt. Geht man davon aus dass es keine noch-mehr-Vergangenheit-Form als das Plusquamperfekt gibt, dann müsste man Hilfskonstrukte verwenden um die Zeitrelation klarzustellen, z.B.:

> ... er hatte sich morgens um fünf aus dem Haus geschlichen, da hatte sie noch geschlafen, er dagegen **war bis zu diesem Zeitpunkt überhaupt noch nicht zu Schlaf gekommen** und war auch, nachdem er sie verlassen hatte, noch wach geblieben und ein bisschen durch die Gegend gelaufen...

Regener vermeidet dies indem er die (nicht unbedingt standardskonforme) Ultraperfekt-Form einsetzt, welche ebensodeutlich den nicht-Schlaf zeitlich auf vor-5:00 positioniert.

Viele Deutschlehrer würden das sicherlich als Fehler anstreichen, aber wie David Vogt zitiert kann man solchartige Itaration der Vergangenheits-Bestimmungen durchaus als logische Extrapolation der Tempusprinzipien betrachten.

In jeden Fall ist der ganze Roman nicht unbedingt als "sprachlich perfekt" geschrieben, sondern mischt bewusst literarische mit eher umgangssprachlichen Formen. Zum Beispiel ist das ganze Zitat etwas fragwürdig in der Satzstruktur: man würde eigentlich nach "geschlichen" einen Punkt oder ein Semikolon setzen.
Dies ist vielleicht am besten begründet via den Vorgängerroman *Herr Lehmann* (der erzählerisch nach *Neue Vahr* gesetzt ist). Selbiger spielt fast vollständig in verschiedenen Kneipen, mit Personen die sich einerseits öfters in philosophischen Betrachtungen versuchen, und recht gewählt ausdrücken, andererseits aber nicht über einen gewissen Alkoholpegel hinwegtäuschen können. Ich würde das nicht speziell mit Bremen verbinden (*Herr Lehmann* spielt in Berlin).

Comment: Danke! Wieso muss man einen Punkt oder ein Semikolon benutzen? Ich dachte, man darf auch im eigentlich korinthenkackerischen deutschen (im Gegensatz zum englischen) Hauptsätze mit einem schlichten Komma anschließen, was Regener auch nochmal nach "schlafen" macht.

Comment: @cruthers deshalb meine Beschreibung als "fragwürdig". Man _darf_ Haupsätze mit einem einfachen Komma verbinden, ja. Man _darf_ auch Wörter wie "Hauptsatzaneinanderreihungslegalitätsbekräftungsrelativierungsbeispiel" verwenden, ohne dass dies aber zu empfehlen ist.